# How to create multiple log files programmatically in Log4j2 based on multiple dynamic parameters?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Is there a way to create multiple log files programmatically in Log4j2 based on multiple dynamic parameters? For example, for the input parameter "abc", the program should create "abc.log" and for the input parameter "xyz", it should create "xyz.log". The number of dynamic parameters is not known in advance. There are also no limits to the number of dynamic parameters.

For example, the following dynamic approach works in the older Log4j 1.2. Need your help to come up with a simple equivalent approach in Log4j2. Thanks.

```
    /**
     * Equivalent Log4j 1.2 code for REFERENCE PURPOSES ONLY
     */
    public static Logger getDynamicLogger(String parameter){
        Logger logger = null;
        try {
            SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
            RollingFileAppender appender = null;
            logger = Logger.getLogger(parameter);
            String path = "/opt/logs/";
            appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, path + parameter+".log", true);
            logger.addAppender(appender);
            appender.setImmediateFlush(true);
            appender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
            appender.setMaximumFileSize(1000000);
            logger.setAdditivity(false);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while creating dynamic logger",e);
        }
        return logger;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) which provides support for the dynamic logging requirements as documented here in the [Log4j 2.x FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files). But, given that the requirements are different, the following approach was useful.

```java
    public static Logger getLogger(String parameter){
        String path = "/opt/logs/";
        final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("10MB");
        DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("20", "1", null, null, null, false, config);
        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config).withPattern(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN).build();

        Appender appender = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(path+parameter+".log", path+parameter+"-%i.log",
                "true", parameter, "true", "128", "true", policy, strategy, layout, (Filter) null, "false", "false", (String) null, config);

        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);

        AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(parameter, null, null);
        AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, Level.INFO, parameter, "true", refs, null, config, null );
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
        config.addLogger(parameter, loggerConfig);
        ctx.updateLoggers();
        return LogManager.getLogger(parameter);
    }
```